# How to query the user's post?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I currently have my system set up through parse.com

What Im trying to do is to be able to in a `tableView` or a `PFQuerTableViewController` be able to query the post which is a `PFObject` that my user has posted. Currently I have this code below and its only saying "Loading.." instead of displaying their postings. Why is it not displaying my user's last posts?

This is the query in which Im trying to fetch the users post:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
    [postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    // Run the query
    [postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //Save results and update the table
            postArray = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}
```

And here is its cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    // If you want a custom cell, create a new subclass of PFTableViewCell, set the cell identifier in IB, then change this string to match
    // You can access any IBOutlets declared in the .h file from here and set the values accordingly
    // "Cell" is the default cell identifier in a new Master-Detail Project
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    //cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];
    //cell.imageView.file = [object objectForKey:self.imageKey];
    PFObject *post = [postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[post objectForKey:@"title"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Also here is the code for how I am posting the PFObject:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFObject *quoteNew = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"New"];
    [quoteNew setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"quoteText"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self attributionTitle] text] forKey:@"title"];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Uploading";
    [hud show:YES];

    [quoteNew saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //[self done:self];
            [hud hide:YES];

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {

             [hud hide:YES];

        }

    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run the query in the `queryForTable` method. That's not what it's for. In `queryForTable`, you're supposed to build the query with the constraints that you want (like the author thing that you added) then return the query. So for your case:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
    [postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    // Don't run the query, return it so PFQueryTableViewcontroller can use it
    return postQuery;
}
```

If you want to programmatically tell your PFQueryTableViewController to load new posts, you can run `[self loadObjects]`.

Note: This only applies if you are subclassing PFQueryTableViewController

I'd recommend reading the documentation, it lays everything out fairly well [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS).

Comment: Would I add "author" when I post the PFObject? Would I change the code below to add "Author"?                                                'PFObject *quoteNew = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"New"];
    [quoteNew setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"quoteText"];
    [quoteNew setObject:[[self attributionTitle] text] forKey:@"title"];'

Comment: When are you trying to create the new object? In your question, you have it in an IBOutlet - do you want to run it when the user clicks on something?

Comment: Yes when I create the object would I have to incorporate "Author"?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the key as user

```
[quoteNew setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
```

Then querying for author

```
[postQuery whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Try instead

```
[postQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```